# Unable to Export MacOS Archive using Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I've recently renewed my developer membership and am attempting to export an archive of a MacOS application not intended for the App store.  The documentation suggests that the Export button would be illuminated when selecting an archive.  However, that is not my case.

I ensured that my provisioning profile, certficiates etc. are on my Mac and all appears to be in order.  What other remedies should I attempt in order to export the archive?  My intent is to send to my customer for testing and internal use in the workgroup.

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a provisioning issue where I had renewed my subscription.  The provisioning profile had to also be transferred to my new Mac from the old one.